# Compute length of a model

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have this `productsCount` computed property which should count all `products` but it always returns a 0. Why is that and how can I fix it?

**controller.js**

```
productsCount: Ember.computed('model.products', function() {
  var products = this.get('model.products');
  return products.get('length');
}),
```

**route.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return {
      products: this.store.find('product')
    };
  }
});
```

Comment: I doubt if the problem is that the CP "always returns zero". Did you trace through it? The problem is almost certanly that the CP "is not getting called when length changes"--which is because, uhh, you're not telling it to recompute when length changes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `model.products` passed in your computed property, will just trigger when `this.get('model').set('products', [...])` is called. But because `products` is an array like object the `length` property probably is changed when someone call `products.pushObject(...)` which will not make your computed property recompute because the `products` array reference isn't changed, just your contents.

To fix this you have to add `.length` to your computed property dependent key, like so:

```
productsCount: Ember.computed('model.products.length', function() {
  return this.get('model.products.length');
})
```

Since you're just aliasing an property, you can take advantage of [Ember.computed.alias](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html#method_alias), and simplify your code to:

```
productsCount: Ember.computed.alias('model.products.length')
```

There are other very useful computed macros in `Ember.computed.*` you may want to give a look in the [docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html) for further information